# multiple files upload with only PHP and mysql

Tags: php, arrays, upload

I am trying to create a dynamic multiple file upload system where the user specifies the number of files to be uploaded. After the selection is made, the corresponding number of file upload fields are created and then the user can make the upload.

Below is the script that I have. From my debugging the array is created successfully, but the upload fails. I will really appreciate some help if someone tells me what I am doing wrong.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" name="max">
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
      <td >no of products</td>
       <td><input name="max2" type="text" id="max2" size="3" maxlength="2" />
        </td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="go" id="go" value="go&gt;&gt;" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="uploader" id="uploader"><table>
  <tr>
<td>

   <?php
global $max;
if(isset($_POST['max2']))
    $max = $_POST['max2'];
else
    $max = 3;

for ($i = 1; $i <= $max; $i++) {
$forms = '<table>
          <tr>
            <td>File</td>
            <td><label for="uploader"></label>
              <input name="uploader'.$i.'" type="file" id="uploader'.$i.'" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>';
echo $forms.'<br>';//// creates a new form field depending on number of files specified by user
}
?>
 <input name="max3" type="hidden" id="max" value="<?php echo $_POST['max2'] ?>" />
 <?php
  if(isset($_POST['upload'])){

$uploadArray= array();
for ($i = 1;$i <= $_POST['max3']; $i++) {
$uploadArray[] = $_FILES['uploader'.$i]['name'];
        }
print_r ($uploadArray); // display array to check it was properly created


 foreach($uploadArray as $file) {

    $target_path = "../Users/storename/upload/";

        if(file_exists($target_path) && is_dir($target_path)){

                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$file]["tmp_name"], $target_path.'new'.$file)) {
                     echo "<br> The file ".  basename( $_FILES['$file']['name'])." has been uploaded";
                } 
                else{
                    echo "<br>The file ".$file." has NOT been uploaded";
                }

    }
    else{
    echo 'invalid path<br>';
    echo $target_path;
    }
}
}

?></td>
     </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input type="submit" name="upload" id="upload" value="Submit" /></td>
  </tr>
  </table>

</form>
```

Comment: you do not wanna use jquery.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are ready to use jquery try this for [multiple uploads](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/).